# Displaying Rating star from Data-table column render is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatables, rating

I have used server side datatable for some of the reason and i am trying to display rating stars from one of the column, all the data correctly displaying,

> Here is my .js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    table = $('.dataTables-example').DataTable({ 
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo base_url('admin/Review/get_Data')?>",
            "type": "POST"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "review_id", "name":"review_id"},
            { "data": "hotel_name", "name":"hotel_name"},
            { "data": "review_by", "name":"review_by"},
            { "data": "review_title", "name":"review_title"},
            { "data": "review_desc",
                "render":function(data, type, row){
                    var review = row.review_desc;
                    var id = row.review_id;
                    if(row.review_desc.length > 50) {
                        var desc = '<div class="showbox">'+review.substring(0, 50)+'</div><span class="'+id+'more" style="display:none;">'+review.substring(50)+'</span><br><span onclick="see_more('+id+')" class="'+id+'readmore" style="color:red; cursor:pointer;">See More</span><span class="'+id+'nomore" onclick="nomore('+id+')" style="color:red;display:none; cursor:pointer;">See Less</span>'; 
                    }
                    else{
                        var desc = review;
                    };
                    return desc; 
                },searchable: false, sortable: false
            },
            { "data": "created_at",
                render: function(created_at){
                    return moment(created_at).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A");
                }
            },
            { "data": "rating_star",
                render: function(rating_star){
                    return '<div class="star_rating_customer_reviews"><input value="'+rating_star+'" type="number" class="rating" min=0 max=5 step=0.1 data-size="sm" data-stars="5" href="#" readonly="true"></div>';
                }, searchable: false, sortable: false
            }
        ],
        "order": [ 0, 'desc' ],
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 0 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Here, i am trying to display rating star from column **rating_star** external rating css and js are not applying on that and it display like,

[image]

Look at the raings column it displays input field,
and i have done it in html like,

```
<div class="star_rating_customer_reviews"><input value="1" type="number" class="rating" min=0 max=5 step=0.1 data-size="sm" data-stars="5" href="#" readonly="true"></div>
```

It displaying perfectly above the select num of record to display dropdown. which looks like that external scripts are not accessing from datatable column.
I am stuck in this,

```
       { "data": "rating_star",
            render: function(rating_star){
                return '<div class="star_rating_customer_reviews"><input value="'+rating_star+'" type="number" class="rating" min=0 max=5 step=0.1 data-size="sm" data-stars="5" href="#" readonly="true"></div>';
            }, searchable: false, sortable: false
        }
```

Please help me out,
used ajax datatable :- [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html)

and the rating plugin i have used is :- [star rating](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
 columns:..,
 order: ...,
 createdRow: function (row, data, dataIndex) {

                            // any manipulation in the row element
                           var ratingInput = $(row).find('.rating');
                           $(ratingInput).rating();

                        }
```

Comment: Wowwww,
its working bro.. i am socked :)
I had searched every where but found nothing....
thnx a lot brooo...

Comment: You welome bro. Happy coding :) @Rits

Comment: But i find everywhere found nothing, where you found this?? is there another methods? i would like to know

Comment: I took the idea from here: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html @Rits